# Javascript regex is grouping a literal parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
const str = `zell class="www-some" bro and class="ded_Me" or addClass('coolman') also addClass("boo-boo")`;

const allCssClassRegex = /addClass\(["|']([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)["|']\)|class=["|']([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)["|']/gi;
let match;

while ((match = allCssClassRegex.exec(str)) != null) {
    console.log(match);
}
```

I'm trying to match two patterns and have the second member of the array be the match. The output looks like:

```
[ 'class="www-some"',
  undefined,
  'www-some',
  index: 5,
  input: 'zell class="www-some" bro and class="ded_Me" or addClass(\'coolman\') also addClass("boo-boo")' ]
[ 'class="ded_Me"',
  undefined,
  'ded_Me',
  index: 30,
  input: 'zell class="www-some" bro and class="ded_Me" or addClass(\'coolman\') also addClass("boo-boo")' ]
[ 'addClass(\'coolman\')',
  'coolman',
  undefined,
  index: 48,
  input: 'zell class="www-some" bro and class="ded_Me" or addClass(\'coolman\') also addClass("boo-boo")' ]
[ 'addClass("boo-boo")',
  'boo-boo',
  undefined,
  index: 73,
  input: 'zell class="www-some" bro and class="ded_Me" or addClass(\'coolman\') also addClass("boo-boo")' ]
```

It appears that the literal `(` it somehow being interpreted as a group because it the second member of match is undefined (and 1, 2 slots are matches).

How do I go about fixing this regex to have the second array slot be the match only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues with your pattern, and it can probably be condensed somewhat:

```
/(?:addClass[(]*|class=)["']([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)["'][)]*/gi;
```

Also inside a character class `[9-_]` implies `9` *through* `_`, which you probably don't want. If you rearrange the characters so that it's like `[9_-]` (where the "-") is at the end then it will work.